# Match two columns and return speific value

Tags: excel

I have to match two columns and return a value after matching them.

- Column A: List of 5000 products (products repeat)
- Column B: "Return the code of product"
- Column C: List of 20 unique products
- Column D: Code of 20 unique products

What formula should be used to match A and C to return value in B from D?

Comment: Use Index/Match function. Some sample data will help visitors to understand you need as well as show some effort what you have tried yet?

Comment: Check `VLOOKUP` function and its usage. It should get you the results you need.